# Is this how you state your university, graduate school, department, and major?

Tags: word-order

> OOO University, Graduate School of Language Education, Language Education, Department of Language Education

where the format is: University, Graduate School, Major, Department

This is to be stated in the abstract of a thesis at top, and I'm wondering if this is in the correct order? ('Language Education' is a made up major/department)

Comment: If you're trying to find the standard form in educational circles, this isn't really the right place to ask. I think you should visit [Academia.SE] for that info.

Comment: It's not really appropriate for Academia either because it's too specific. You should look at previously published theses in your department or ask your advisor or administrative assistant or possibly the Graduate school who may have a template or other guide on how to format a thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the hierarchy from less to more **specific** is:

> **University**
>   **Graduate School**
>   **Department**
>   **Major**

but depending on the purpose you have, it may be different.
In a resume it would be

> **Graduate School** or **Department**
>   **University**
>   **Major**

**Department** is usually implied if a **Graduate School** is given